# Problems in nodejs callback in custom alexa skill

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to create a custom Alexa skill in which I am calling an API. But somehow my code is behaving weird.

**CASE - 1**

```
'firstChance': function () {

    // Some code here//

    getJSON(options, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log('ERROR while trying to get country names', err);
        }

         console.log(result);
    });
    this.emit(':tell', speechOutput, speechOutput);
},
```

In this case no errors are shown in cloudwatch but the control is not going to **getJSON** function eventhough **this.emit()** function is executed.

Below are the cloudwatch logs:

```
    CloudWatch logs:

  
13:42:49
START RequestId: ************ Version: $LATEST


13:42:49
2018-04-03T13:42:49.578Z    *************** Warning: Application ID is not set


13:42:49
END RequestId: *********************


13:42:49
REPORT RequestId: **************    Duration: 74.03 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 48 MB


13:42:51
START RequestId: ***************** Version: $LATEST


13:42:51
2018-04-03T13:42:51.647Z    *********************** Warning: Application ID is not set


13:42:51
END RequestId: *************************


13:42:51
REPORT RequestId: ************************  Duration: 153.09 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 49 MB
```

**CASE 2 :**

```
'firstChance': function () {

    // Some code here//


    getJSON(options, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log('ERROR while trying to get country names', err);
        }

         console.log(result);
    });
    //this.emit(':tell', speechOutput, speechOutput);
},
```

In this case even though there are no errors in the logs and the control is going to getJSON, but alexa says "There was a problem with the requested skill's response".

```
    Below are the cloudwatch logs:


13:35:32
START RequestId: ************************** Version: $LATEST


13:35:32
2018-04-03T13:35:32.896Z    e16ddc70-3743-11e8-bf3b-a98fb0c89baf    Warning: Application ID is not set


13:35:32
END RequestId: **************************


13:35:32
REPORT RequestId: **************************    Duration: 110.81 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 48 MB


13:35:35
START RequestId: ************************** Version: $LATEST


13:35:35
2018-04-03T13:35:35.549Z    **************************  Warning: Application ID is not set


13:35:35
2018-04-03T13:35:35.861Z    **************************  Response from Server started


13:35:35
2018-04-03T13:35:35.861Z    **************************  Server Status: 200


13:35:35
2018-04-03T13:35:35.861Z    **************************  Response Headers : {"server":"Cowboy","connection":"close","x-powered-by":"Express","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","content-length":"187238","etag":"W/\"Vhlms2jCBxpTPF7sp9mxAw==\"","vary":"Accept-Encoding","date":"Tue, 03 Apr 2018 13:35:35 GMT","via":"1.1 vegur"}


13:35:35
2018-04-03T13:35:35.978Z    **************************  Preparing the hash map...


13:35:36
2018-04-03T13:35:35.978Z    **************************  [ { name: { common: 'Afghanistan', official: 'Islamic Republic of Afghanistan', native: [Object] }, tld: [ '.af' ], cca2: 'AF', ccn3: '004', cca3: 'AFG', currency: [ 'AFN' ], callingCode: [ '93' ], capital: 'Kabul', altSpellings: [ 'AF', 'Afġānistān' ], relevance: '0', region:


13:35:36
END RequestId: **************************


13:35:36
REPORT RequestId: **************************    Duration: 1249.65 ms    Billed Duration: 1300 ms Memory Size: 128 MB    Max Memory Used: 57 MB


13:35:36
START RequestId: ************************** Version: $LATEST


13:35:36
2018-04-03T13:35:36.954Z    e46c4ff4-3743-11e8-a19e-036de9469172    Warning: Application ID is not set


13:35:36
END RequestId: **************************


13:35:36
REPORT RequestId: **************************    Duration: 1.97 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 57 MB
```

I am not able to resolve this. 
I think, I have made some mistake in the callback of getJSON().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `getJSON` is an asynchronous function: meaning it returns immediately and it calls you back when the results are ready, or when an error is thrown.

So, in your example, `getJSON` is invoked, but it returns immediately, followed by your call to `this.emit(':tell')` which ends your handler and sends the respobse back to Alexa before `getJSON` has a chance to complete and call your anonymous function callback.

To solve, move `this.emit(...)` inside the callback function you are passing into `getJSON`

```
 getJSON(options, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        // handle the error
        this.emit(':tell', 'Error getting country names');
        return console.log('ERROR while trying to get country names', err);
    }

     console.log(result);
     // handle the successful result
     this.emit(':tell', 'The country name was retrieved!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Either try this,

```
    'firstChance': function () {

    // Some code here//

    getJSON(options, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log('ERROR while trying to get country names', err);
        }

         console.log(result);
         this.emit(':tell', speechOutput, speechOutput);
    });

},
```

Or you can use set timeout :

```
        'firstChance': function () {

        // Some code here//

        getJSON(options, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log('ERROR while trying to get country names', err);
            }

             console.log(result);
        });

        setTimeout(() => {

             this.emit(':tell', speechOutput, speechOutput);
          }, 2500)       


    },
```

Or you can try Async - Await which are now natively available in AWS Lambda as mentioned here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-8-10-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/